# Node.js completely remove file in a running script

Tags: node.js, file, filesystems, posix

I have a `Node.js` script that is running in a `while (true)` fashion and watches directories for certain files and removes them using `unlink` `API`:

```
fs.unlinkSync(path);
```

The files are not created by `Node` process, but as `POSIX` documentation about `unlink` says, files are not removed from disk until process is closed, thus `lsof` will list them as `(deleted)` and tied to `node` process.

My script is some kind of a `"watchdog"`, so **how would I go to removing those files and cleaning up disk space without restarting the `Node` process itself?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try `child_process`:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
execSync(`rm ${filePath}`)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about, but seems a bit ugly to go there, but not sure if there's a better solution.